# Proving the following function from the metric space $(VxV, \max\{d,d\})$ to R is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

In the question below, I understand what needs to be done *in theory* (show that $F^{-1}\big((a,b)\big) \in T_{d_{\max\{d,d\}}}$ for $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$), but I am at a loss as to how to start this. My main problem (I think) is with the definition of $\max\{d,d\}$ - what are the two metrics here? Or have I completely misinterpreted the domain? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Let $V$ be an inner product space with the inner product denoted $<,>$, and let $d$ be the metric induced on $V$ by $<,>$. Prove that $F:(VxV, \max\{d,d\})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $F(u,v)=<u,v>$ is continuous. The topology is the Euclidean topology. There is also a hint for using Cauchy–Schwarz: $<u,v>^2 \leq <u,u><v,v>$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\max \{d,d\}$ is the metric on $V \times V$ defined by $\max \{d,d\} ((x,y),(u,v))=\max \{d(x,u),d(y,v)\}$.

$$|F(x,y)-F(u,v)|=|\langle x, y \rangle-\langle u, v \rangle|$$ $$\leq  |\langle x, y \rangle-\langle x, v \rangle|+|\langle x, v \rangle-\langle u, v \rangle|$$ $$\leq \|x\|\|y-v\|+\|v\|\|x-u\|.$$ This does not exceed $\max \{\|y-v\|,\|x-u\|\} (\|x\|+\|v\|)$. Can you finish?